# Can't attach custom layout to Activity dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

When I create Activity and set new RelativeLayout right in onCreate(), all works fine.
But I think it's more convenient to create a class MView that extends RelativeLayout and do all the settings there. And if I do this, Activity stays empty. What should I change in MView (or shall I need to use RelativeLayout without extension)?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

RelativeLayout mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);//Change this to MView mLayout=new MView(this);
//I've been trying to move text from here...
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("TestText");
tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceSmall);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

mLayout.addView(tv);
//... to here to MView class that extends RelativeLayout

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

setContentView(mLayout, rlp);
}
```

So, code for MView constructor is:

```
public MView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("TestText");
    tv.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    this.addView(tv);
}
```

And onCreate becomes this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MView mLayout = new MView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    setContentView(mLayout, rlp);
}
```

Comment: try without adding LayoutParams to setContentView. Use setContentView(mLayout);

Comment: Is the code above the working code, or is it the faulty code?  Perhaps post your MView layout initialization code.

Comment: setContentView(mayout) still shows nothing.

Comment: Create relative virw in MView and then create textview in it

Answer (score 0):

1. It is better to set layout parmas to direct view rather than when you add another layout.
2. In your case, set wrong add rules for text now.

Corrected code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        mLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("TestText");
        tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceSmall);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlt = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rlt.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        tv.setLayoutParams(rlt);

        mLayout.addView(tv);
        setContentView(mLayout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but can you tell why shall I do all settings in onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

It was VERY simple. When I created MView, my implementation of onLayout was empty. Obviously, I had to write

```
super.onLayout(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

And it worked fine. Thanks for helping :)